# regarding showing different view on each item click in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have 5 items in a listview,I have to show different view on each click at the item,,,How to do this,also i have to put an arrow on the left and right side of the each item,,,

Here is my listview java code

http://pastebin.com/LsunQU9z

and here is my listview xml

http://pastebin.com/1S4uD5mH

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: your question not clear? where you want to show item or background?...

Comment: @llango,,,,dere are 5 items in the listview

Comment: what will be happened when click on the list item?

Comment: @llango,,,,all the items are in string format....so how to apply on item click ???

Comment: can you explain exactly what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
            {
                   switch(position)

                   case 0:
                  //write for first item
                   break;
                   case 1:
                 //second
                   break;
                   case 2:
                 //third
                   break; 
                    case 3:
                 //for
                   break;

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends on what you are going to do or show in those 5 items.

One way would be to only use one class, let's call it ShowActivity and then pass extras to that activity to see what it should show. And then just fetch that in onCreate in the ShowActivity. 
One way would just to show it in the activity that you are in. 
Two different examples are below:

```
   lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ITEM_INDEX",position);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

With the one above use something similar in the onCreate @ ShowActivity

```
    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("ITEM_INDEX", 0);
    switch(id) {
    case 0:
        //Show item 0
        break;
    case 1:
        //Show item 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //Show item 2
        break;
    case 3:
        //Show item 3
        break;
    case 4:
        //show item 4
        break;
    }
```

This is the second example, use this in your list activity.

```
   lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {

            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                //Show item 0
                break;
            case 1:
                //Show item 1
                break;
            case 2:
                //Show item 2
                break;
            case 3:
                //Show item 3
                break;
            case 4:
                //show item 4
                break;
            }

        }
    });
```